# Future promises in Clojure hangs on me

Tags: concurrency, clojure

When I run the following code it basically works how I intend it to, except that it hangs after the future is finished. What am I missing - some kind of "close agents/threads" call? How should I do this?

```
(def name-to-greet (promise))

(future
    (println "Hello," @name-to-greet))

(print "What is your name? ")
(flush)
(deliver name-to-greet (read-line))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Futures use the agent thread pool, which uses non-daemon threads, which means Clojure won't shut down till you call [(shutdown-agents)](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/shutdown-agents).  imho, this is bogus (see [my comments here](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/06/08/clojure-agent-thread-pools/)) and I've made suggestions that Rich said he would consider post-1.2 around this.