# problems with spwaning process from within uberjar

Tags: java, clojure, process, uberjar

When the following Clojure sample program is packed into a standalone uberjar (via boot-clj), the execution of `java -jar app.jar` behaves different from invoking the `-main` function from within the development repl.

```
(ns bat-man.core
  (:require [clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (prn (sh "echo" "test")))
```

What happens, is that the result `{:exit 0, :out "test\n", :err ""}` is printed immediately to `stdout`, but after that it takes along time, maybe half a minute, until the program actually exits.
Which is not the case, when the program is modified to just print some output wihtout invoking `sh`.

Within the development repl, everything is as expected, the function finishes immediately after printing. How can that be explained/fixed?

*Update: Here is an excerpt from `ps aux` taken meanwhile the program is taking its time to finish:*

```
unsername         8730  5.4  2.0 3643576 80052 pts/8   Sl+  13:25   0:01 java -jar /path/to/app.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

`clojure.java.shell/sh` uses a `future` behind the scenes, so you need to call `(shutdown-agents)` to shutdown background threads.

Comment: Does this solution work? IIRC futures and agents use different thread pools.

Comment: Seems to remain the same behavior. Maybe helpful, from the docs of shutdown-agents: "Running actions will complete, but no new actions will be accepted"

Comment: @OlegTheCat Yes, this should work.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393497/future-promises-in-clojure-hangs-on-me